# layout.xml : change item renderer in checkout_onepage_review

Tags: overrides, layout

I would like to change the item listing presentation in the checkout page.

I then made a custom checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml file and in my module layout file I defined it based on the original magento declaration:

```
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Overview</label>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
            <label>Items Before</label>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
            <label>Items After</label>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
        <label>Additional Product Info</label>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

It works, but is it mandatory to re-define all that ?

I have tried :

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><value>checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
```

But that does not work..?

Thank you for your help

Comment: this should work. did you define it in the `local.xml` of your template?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP has not responded to a comment in over 3 months.